# Conditional Function in R

Tags: r

I have an R function `for (i in 1:10)` that reads in data and performs some cleaning. Is it possible to write a flexible statement to execute certain parts of the code conditionally, for example have different steps for i = 2 and 8?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. Your question is very vague. Please add more details in future questions and make sure you describe your problem in a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add conditions inside the loop if you want:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  if (i<=2){print("1-2")}
  if (i>2){print(" >2")}
}
```